# draggable image behind top image layer

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, draggable

I have created a (draggable/zoomable) image area via an upload link, and would like to have a transparent mask image overlaying it, whilst still being able to drag and zoom the background.

The problem being that once the mask is overlayed - the drag/zoom area stops as it is behind the mask layer.

I cant Z-Index the order as it looses the mask behind the zoomed image.

Have tried re-positioning it over with "Position:absolute & relative".

Have been all around the web to no joy to a solution!

Have attached an image to make it more clearer hopefully.

code:

```
        <div class="GridRight">
    <div class="zoom_outer">
        <div id="zoom">
    <img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
    </div>
        </div>
    
    
        <div class="OverlayImage">
        <img  src="img/TESTER.webp" alt=""/>
        </div>


        <script>
        var scale = 1,
        panning = false,
        pointX = 0,
        pointY = 0,
        start = { x: 0, y: 0 },
        zoom = document.getElementById("zoom");

      function setTransform() {
        zoom.style.transform = "translate(" + pointX + "px, " + pointY + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
      }

      zoom.onmousedown = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        start = { x: e.clientX - pointX, y: e.clientY - pointY };
        panning = true;
      }

      zoom.onmouseup = function (e) {
        panning = false;
      }

      zoom.onmousemove = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!panning) {
          return;
        }
        pointX = (e.clientX - start.x);
        pointY = (e.clientY - start.y);
        setTransform();
      }

      zoom.onwheel = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var xs = (e.clientX - pointX) / scale,
          ys = (e.clientY - pointY) / scale,
          delta = (e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.deltaY);
        (delta > 0) ? (scale *= 1.2) : (scale /= 1.2);
        pointX = e.clientX - xs * scale;
        pointY = e.clientY - ys * scale;

        setTransform();
      }// JavaScript Document

        </script>
        <script>
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }   
        </script>
```

Thanks[example overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exSXA.jpg)

Comment: Try and apply `pointer-events: none;` to `.OverlayImage`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Superb!!! Genius!!! Many, many thanks!